# Mongoose Schema Instance Methods is Not a Function

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I've have had a working version of mongoose instance methods working before. I'm not sure what is different about it this time around. The only thing I have done differently this time is that I separated the mongoose connection function outside of the `server.js` file into a config file that will be imported and call the `connect()` function.

I will mostly use this instance method in passport with the local strategy to log in the user. When I go to call my instance method on the user instance that was found by the previous `UserModel.findOne({ email })` the `verify(password)` instance method is not called and does not throw any errors.

For testing purposes, I've tried to hard code a `UserModel.findOne()` right into connection field and I do get a user back. I then decided to call my instance method right off of the returned user instance named `verify()`.

I have also attempted changing the name of the method to `comparePassword`, I've tried testing with statics to check if it is even called at all (which it wasn't), I've also tried to research other ways to import my schemas and models, and that does not seem to work. I have experimented with Async/Await hasn't changed the output

---

**File: `mongo.db.js`**

```
const connect = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoose.connect(
      config.get('DB.STRING'),
      { useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true },
      async (err) => {
        if (err) reject(err)
        resolve()
        // TESTING INSTANCE METHODS
        await mongoose.connection
          .collection('users')
          // HARD CODED TEST EMAIL
          .findOne({ email: 'braden_feeney@hotmail.com' }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            console.log(result)
            console.log(result.verify('test1234'))
          })
      },
    )
  })
}

const close = () => {
  return mongoose.disconnect()
}

export default { connect, close }
```

---

**File: `passport.config.js`**

```
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'password',
    },
    async (email, password, done) => {
      try {
        // Find the user given the email
        const user = await User.findOne({ email })
        // If not found
        if (!user) return done(null, false)
        // Check if the password is correct
        const isValididated = await user.verify(password)
        // If not matched
        if (!isValididated) return done(null, false)

        // Return the user
        done(null, user)
      } catch (error) {
        done(error, false)
      }
    },
  ),
)
```

---

**File: `users.model.js`**

```
const UserSchema = new Schema(
  // HIDDEN FOR SECURITY
  { ... },
  { versionKey: false, timestamps: true },
)

// HIDDEN FOR SECURITY - PRE SAVE WORKS AS EXPECTED
UserSchema.pre('save', async function(next) { ... })

// THIS IS THE METHOD THAT SHOWS AS 'Not a Function'
UserSchema.methods.verify = function(password) {
  bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return new Error(err)
    return res
  })
}

export default model('User', UserSchema)
```

When I call `user.verify(password)` I expect to see a Boolean value either get returned from the function.

The actual result is an Error thrown stating
`TypeError: user.verify is not a function`

Comment: Can you `console.log(user)` after the `await User.findOne({ email })` and see what it looks like?

Comment: @Akrion

{ _id: 5d010bb74b129397607e2abb,
  _workspaceID: 5d003c0c34aea526f8c44b65,
  firstName: 'Arlie',
  lastName: 'Veum',
  email: 'braden_feeney@hotmail.com',
  password: '...',
  createdAt: 2019-06-12T14:27:03.210Z,
  updatedAt: 2019-06-12T14:27:03.210Z }

This result is what is back, I am getting the user back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering around with how mongoose creates instance methods, I tried using another way to make the method work. I had to wrap the `bcrypt.compare()` in a promise because my code wasn't waiting for a response.

**File: `users.model.js`**

```
UserSchema.method('verify', function(password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, (err, res) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      resolve(res)
    })
  })
})
```

I still prefer the way that is mentioned in my question because I believe it looks cleaner and is not relying on a string to be the method name.

Answer (score 0):

This section does not make sense:

```
async (email, password, done) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email })
        if (user) // <-- if you have a user record
          return done(null, false) // <-- you return!
        // There was no valid user ... how would there be user.verify?
        const isValididated = await user.verify(password)
        if (!isValididated) return done(null, false)
          done(null, user)
    } catch (error) {
        done(error, false)
    }
}
```

You seem to return on valid user but calling `user.verify` when you do not have a user. So it seems your flow is somewhat problematic.

Comment: Yes, you're right on that one it's supposed to be `if (!user) return done(null, false)`. This would have been caught either way later on, but I still receive the issue with the instance method.

Comment: Yes, I still get the error when it gets to the `user.verify(password)` section

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is just mark this function with "async".

```
// THIS IS THE METHOD THAT SHOWS AS 'Not a Function'
UserSchema.methods.verify = async function (password) {
  bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return new Error(err)
    return res
  })
}
```

& Another thing that you've to keep in mind is that when you're retrieving user from your DB make sure to use the "await" keyword there as well.
I was getting the same error and then I noticed that I forgot to use the "await" keyword and my code goes to the next line without even waiting for the "user" to arrive from DB and we don't have a user or instance and we're calling "compare" method on that instance which hasn't arrived from DB.

That's why you were getting error that comparePassword is not a function.